# Segmentation fault ao ler arquivo

Tags: c

Tenho um header inputstream.h que define uma struct possuindo uma string, um int e uma function readc. Neste header defino a function init recebendo como parâmetro uma string possuindo o diretório absoluto de um arquivo, e a struct inputstream, nesta function leio o arquivo e passo os dados para a variável source do inputstream. Aqui vai o código:

**inputstream.h**

```
#ifndef INPUTSTREAM_H
#define INPUTSTREAM_H

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *source; // header source code
    int pos;

    char (*readc)();

}inputstream;

void init(const char*, inputstream*);

#endif
```

**inputstream.c**

```
#include "inputstream.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

inputstream *is;

char readc()
{
    return is->source[is->pos++];
}

void init(const char *file_header, inputstream *stream)
{
    memset(stream, 0, sizeof(inputstream));
    stream->readc = &readc;
    FILE *header = fopen(file_header, "r");

    if (header == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file\nExiting...\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fseek(header, 0, SEEK_END);
    long lenght = ftell(header);

    if (lenght <= 0)
    {
        printf("Empty file\nExiting...\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fseek(header, 0, SEEK_SET);
    stream->source = (char*) malloc(lenght + 2);
    //memset(stream->source, 0, sizeof stream->source);

    fread(stream->source, lenght + 1, 1, file_header);
    fclose(header);
}
```

Quando executo a function init ocorre o erro de segmentation fault.Já debuguei e parece que o problema está na function fread. O que está de errado no código?

Comment: Atenção ao erro tipográfico de `lenght` que deveria ser `length` e é bem comum na nossa lingua. Como está a chamar a função no `main` ?

Comment: init("/home/file.txt", &is);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem alguns erros o seu código. O meu conselho é quando está a programar, avançar com calma e garantir que o que fez para trás lhe parece certo, e ir testando, ao invés de escrever o código todo e testar no fim. Assim no primeiro *segmentation fault* que apanha percebe que o erro está no pouco que já escreveu, e torna-se mais facil de perceber/depurar.

Também preste sempre extrema atenção aos avisos que o compilador dá pois 99.99% deles são erros mesmo. Quando compilo o seu código vejo pelo menos dois avisos: um na linha do `fread`, e outro na chamada ao `init`.

Passando aos problemas:

- No main a chamada é feita com `init("/home/file.txt", &is)` mas a declaração de `is` é :

  ```
  inputstream *is;
  ```

  O que significa que está a passar um `inputstream**` que não é o que a função `void init(const char *file_header, inputstream *stream)` espera. Isto ainda tem outro problema que é, se você passa um ponteiro, é porque não alocou espaço para o conteudo, logo a primeira instrução dentro de `init`:

  ```
  memset(stream, 0, sizeof(inputstream));
  ```

  Regra geral dá *segmentation fault* direto pois o ponteiro `is` não foi inicializado, e não aponta para não definido por si. Logo vai tentar aceder a uma zona de memória "aleatória".

  Tem duas soluções ou aloca espaço para o ponteiro com `malloc` e troca a assinatura da função `init` ou vai pelo mais simples que é criar um objeto `inputstream is;` no `main`. Seguindo esta última solução tem apenas de trocar a função `readc` para:

  ```
  char readc()
  {
      return is.source[is.pos++];
  }
  ```

  Ainda neste ponto, depender de variáveis globais é sempre má ideia. Evite fazer isso.
- O `fread` não tem os parametros certos, nem na ordem certa. Tem ele no seu código assim:

  ```
  fread(stream->source, lenght + 1, 1, file_header);
  ```

  No entanto se consultar a [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) vê que o esperado é:

  ```
  fread (ptr, size, count, stream)

  ptr    - Local na memória a guardar a informação
  size   - Tamanho em bytes de cada elemento
  count  - Quantidade de elementos, cada um com size bytes
  stream - Ponteiro para um objeto FILE como stream de entrada
  ```

  Você tem o `size` trocado com o `count` e o `stream` também não está certo pois deveria ser o respetivo `FILE*`, o `header`.

  Para ficar correto deveria ser:

  ```
  fread(stream->source, 1, lenght + 1, header);
  ```
- Atenção ao erro ortográfico em `lenght`. Embora não afete o código em si, este erro é bem comum para nós portugueses e algo que devemos estar atentos. O correto é `length`.

Comment: Não havia percebido que tinha passado um char* ao invés de um FILE*. A funcão main não está no arquivo inputstream.c,  isso fez você pensar que eu havia declarado o inputstream como pointer, mas eu a declarei como uma sctruct normal.

Comment: Já o fread funcionou normal após eu corrigir o erro, pelo que aprendi o terceiro parâmetro representa o chunk de dado

Comment: @CarlosHenrique Não é o que eu vejo no código da pergunta. Vejo `inputstream *is;`, logo é um pointer.

Comment: Mas esse inputstream pertence ao arquivo inputstream.c, o arquivo principal é o main.c

Comment: @CarlosHenrique No `main` utiliza outro ? Isso mostra como é importante colocar sempre as informações necessárias na pergunta. Posso ter acabado por assumir algo que não era, pois não consigo ver como está o seu `main`.

Comment: Sim isso mesmo, na próxima especifíco mais